# preposition use

Tags: prepositions

Prepositions are always struggle for a non-native speaker.
I can understand the prepositions used in phrasal verbs and some use patterns in adjective phrases.
But I sometimes find the prepositions used for indication some abstract relationships of two nouns are very hard to choose.

E.g. I am writing a paper about women and pregnancies. I cannot decide the preposition in

> pregnancies of/in/from women with depression"

Any materials summarizing such usage?

Answer (score 0):

The preposition **"from"** is incorrect in the context of the sentence you want to use, like the one you mentioned above.

The most appropriate one in this sentence would be "**in"**.

> A study proves that pregnancies in women with depression can be fatal for the unborn baby.

By the way, this is just a random sentence I wrote and tested on a grammar checker tool. I don't know about any studies related to pregnancies and all, I am not a doctor nor a medical student. So please don't take it seriously.

I hope you find this helpful. I would be editing the answer if I find any link related to more study of the prepositions.

For the time being, [this article](https://www.langports.com/useful-tips-to-learn-english-prepositions/) might help you.

Comment: @EllieK I don't think the statement "A pregnancy in a women with depression" is correct. Article shouldn't be used in the beginning of the sentence.

Comment: You are correct.  I deleted my comment.